# Handling Touch Events - onInterceptTouchEvent and onTouchEvent

Tags: android, onclick, touch, touch-event

I want to be able to swipe anywhere on the screen to call a certain function. But I also have `Buttons` in `Linear Layouts` that I want to be able to click on. If I swipe on a `Button` I want  `onInterceptTouchEvent` to `Intercept` the call to the `Button`'s `onTouchEvent` and perform a swipe action. And if I simply click on a `Button` I do not want the `onInterceptTouchEvent` to be called. Rather, I want the `Button`'s `onTouchEvent` to be called and perform a `Button click`

But I get errors when I try implementing `onInterceptTouchEvent`.

Here is my code:

```
public class Game extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_activity);

   //other code....
}
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            swipeScreen(); //if action recognized as swipe then swipe
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            float xDelta = Math.abs(x - mLastX);
            float yDelta = Math.abs(y - mLastY);

            if (yDelta > xDelta) {
                return true;
            }
            break;
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    ButtonOnClick(); //if not a swipe, then button click
    return true;
}
```

First the error says: `The method onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent) of type Game must override or implement a supertype method`

Then instead of `return true` I change the code to:`return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)`  but then I get an error saying: `The method onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent) is undefined for the type Activity`

Can someone please help?

Comment: The `onInterceptTouchEvent()` method is a member of the `ViewGroup` class. To implement it, you'll have to subclass a `ViewGroup` to be used in your layout.

Comment: hm, so how do I subclass my viewgroup? - sorry i'm just new at android

Comment: Thanks i'm getting the hang of it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Note that [`onInterceptTouchEvent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) is a method from the `ViewGroup` class, and not from `Activity`.

You can achieve the desired behavior by moving your logic from `onInterceptTouchEvent()` to [`dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)). Remember to call the superclass implementation of `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` to handle the events that should be handled normally.

Also note that you should consider a movement to be a swipe only when the delta is bigger than the [system constant for touch slop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#getScaledTouchSlop()). And I suggest making sure that the user is swiping in the direction you want by testing `yDelta / 2 > xDelta` instead of `yDelta > xDelta`.

```
public class Game extends Activity {
    private int mSlop;
    private float mDownX;
    private float mDownY;
    private boolean mSwiping;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_activity);

        ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(this)
        mSlop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();

       //other code....
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mDownX = ev.getX();
                mDownY = ev.getY();
                mSwiping = false;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if(mSwiping) {
                    swipeScreen(); //if action recognized as swipe then swipe
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                float x = ev.getX();
                float y = ev.getY();
                float xDelta = Math.abs(x - mDownX);
                float yDelta = Math.abs(y - mDownY);

                if (yDelta > mSlop && yDelta / 2 > xDelta) {
                    mSwiping = true;
                    return true;
                }
                break;
        }

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to do vice versa? I want only click event and not swipe event

Answer (score 0):

I use fernandohur approach (read his [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26387629/2700303)), that is very reusable, self contained and gives everything needed to detect a swipe in any direction.

To use fernandohur `onSwipeListener`, follow these simple steps. All code is written in Kotlin:

```
// 1) Add his onSwipeListener to the project. Credits should go to him

// 2) Implement an anonymous class for the swipe listener:
val onSwipeListener: OnSwipeListener = object : OnSwipeListener() {
    override fun onSwipe(direction: Direction): Boolean {

        if (direction == Direction.Up) {
            //do somethin
            return true
        } else if (direction == Direction.Down) {
            //do something else
            return true
        }
        return super.onSwipe(direction)
    }
}

// 3) connect the listener to the view
val mDetector = GestureDetectorCompat(this.context, onSwipeListener)

// 4) route the touch events to the listener
override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    return if (this.mDetector!!.onTouchEvent(event)) {
        true
    } else super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)
}
```