# hide and show constraintlayout on swipe down and up

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

[image]

I want to make the gradient area swipe-able (down to show, swipe up to hide).

this is my code :

```
val scopeLayout = inflaterView.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.scope_layout)

    scopeLayout.setOnTouchListener({ v, event ->
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ->
                Toast.makeText(context, "you just touch the screen :-)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                scopeLayout.height = 215 // error val cannot be reassigned
        }
        true
    })
```

and I got the error `val cannot be reassigned`. and how to set the height with `dp` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `var` instead of `val` as `val` is immutable.

For how to calculate dp to px you can

```
val Int.dp: Int 
   get() = (this / Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()
val Int.px: Int
   get() = (this * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()
```

And then use it this way `88.dp`

EDIT:

```
scopeLayout.layoutParams = scopeLayout.layoutParams.apply {
    width = ...
    height = ...
}
```

Comment: i changed to this `var scopeLayout = inflaterView.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.scope_layout)` and still error `val cannot be reassigned`

Comment: Have try calling for layout params? added suggestion in my answer's edit. It seems to work it many cases

Comment: it works! i set on swipe up height=70 and on swipe down height = 415. but everytime I swipe down, the height back to 70 again. it seem because it's `ACTION_DOWN` not `ACTION_SWIPE_UP` or something like that. do you know what event i should listen for swipe?

Comment: yeah, action_down  doesn't mean a gesture like swipe down it means that user touched the screen. In android there is such interface as SimpleOnGestureListener. and GestureDetector . There you'll need to write motions that you want to catch with the coordinates of them. You can see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095494/how-to-detect-swipe-direction-between-left-right-and-up-down     , but it's java I believe

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public override bool OnTouchEvent (MotionEvent e)
{
    var action = e.Action;

    switch (action) {
    case MotionEventActions.Pointer3Down:
        Toast.MakeText (this, "hey", ToastLength.Long);

        break;

    case MotionEventActions.PointerUp:

        Toast.MakeText (this, "yo", ToastLength.Long);


        break;
    default:
        break;
    }




    if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Move) {
        return true;
    }

    return base.OnTouchEvent (e);
}
```

I think it helps you

Comment: sorry, I am new to android development. where i put this code?