# How to return previous activity when move to button towards up to the screen on Android?

Tags: android

I would like to return previous screen on Android when user nudge up the button towards the middle of screen ?

How Can I do this on Android ? I am opening this page with a standart button and calling an activity.

Screen

[image: Screen]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13095494/5550161

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect swipe direction between left/right and up/down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095494/how-to-detect-swipe-direction-between-left-right-and-up-down)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the gesture detection class which is inbuilt in java android to handle the action of user flinging the button upwards. I have forked a sample app that outlines how to implement that. Check it out here. 
https://github.com/pkavoo/android-BasicGestureDetect

After detecting the upward fling gesture, implement onBackPressed() there.