# How to fix Scrolling issue of horizontal ViewPager2 and RecyclerView that are inside a vertical RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2

I have a RecyclerView (say, `rootRecyclerView`) that can have different kinds of rows depending on some API response. I implemented one of them is a horizontal `ViewPager2` and another one is implemented with horizontal  `RecyclerView` (say, `childRecyclerView`).

The rootRecyclerView swipes vertically whereas the viewPager2 and childRecyclerView swipes horizontally.

**The Problem:**

When I swipe on the screen, if the swipe is on the the `viewPager2` or `childRecyclerView`, the swipe MUST go perfectly straight horizontally. Otherwise, they won't scroll horizontally; the swipe is taken by the `rootRecyclerView` and so the you would see vertical movement.

So, this happens because your thumb would move in a curved/circular direction creating movement in both the X axis and Y axis, and the so the rootRecyclerView intercepts the swipe creating this unpleasant user experience.

I did try to solve the issue, such as adding an `OnItemTouchListener` to the childRecyclerView like this:

```
    private float Y_BUFFER = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext())
                                     .getScaledPagingTouchSlop(); // 10;
    private float preX = 0f;
    private float preY = 0f;
childRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(@NonNull RecyclerView rv, @NonNull MotionEvent e) {
                if(e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    childRecyclerView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                }
                if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                    if (Math.abs(e.getX() - preX) > Math.abs(e.getY() - preY)) {
                        childRecyclerView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    } else if (Math.abs(e.getY() - preY) > Y_BUFFER) {
                        childRecyclerView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    }
                }
                preX = e.getX();
                preY = e.getY();
                return false;
            }
// ... rest of the code
```

It solves the problem only for the `childRecyclerView`, but I could not solve it for the `ViewPager2`.

I have also tried to use `GestureDetector` as described in this [answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095494/how-to-detect-swipe-direction-between-left-right-and-up-down#26387629), and some other combinations of code, but I could not make it work.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Note that your `Y_BUFFER` is hard-coded to 10 _pixels_. I'd recommend you to use a pre-baked scaled value like `ViewConfiguration.get(getContext()).getScaledPagingTouchSlop()`

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I did not know about it before. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, so after some research, I came to the conclusion of substituting my `ViewPager2` with a `recyclerView` that will 'behave like' a viewPager :/ .

First I replaced my `viewPager2` with a horizontal `recyclerView`. To make it behave like a viewpager, use `SnapHelper`.

```java
RecyclerView childRecyclerView2 = findViewById(R.id.previously_viewPager);
// other init like setup layout manager, adapter etc 
SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(replacedRecyclerView); // <-- this makes out rv behave like a viewPager
```

After that, you have to add an `OnItemTouchListener` and override `onInterceptTouchEvent` just like the code segment in my question:

```java
childRecyclerView2.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(@NonNull RecyclerView rv, @NonNull MotionEvent e) {
// same as the code segment in the question, 
//so skipping this part. 
//just copy it from my question
          }
// ...
}
```

#### Optional:

In viewPager2, you can get the current focus with `getCurrentItem()`, but since we have replaced out viewpager2 with recyclerview, we don't have that method. So, we need to implement our own equivalent version. If you are a Kotlin guy, you can directly jump to the [reference 2](https://medium.com/over-engineering/detecting-snap-changes-with-androids-recyclerview-snaphelper-9e9f5e95c424) and skip this part. Here is the java version if you need, I'll skip the explanation though.
Create `SnapHelperExt.java`

```java
public class SnapHelperExt {

    public SnapHelperExt(){}

    public int getSnapPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, SnapHelper snapHelper){
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        View snapView =  snapHelper.findSnapView(layoutManager);
        if (snapView != null) {
            return layoutManager.getPosition(snapView);
        }else{
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Next create an interface `OnSnapPositionChangeListener` as our listener :

```java
public interface OnSnapPositionChangeListener {
    void onSnapPositionChange(int position);
}
```

After that, create `SnapOnScrollListener.java`:

```java
public class SnapOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    public enum Behavior {
        NOTIFY_ON_SCROLL,
        NOTIFY_ON_SCROLL_STATE_IDLE
    }

    private SnapHelperExt snapHelperExt;
    private SnapHelper snapHelper;
    private Behavior behavior;
    private OnSnapPositionChangeListener onSnapPositionChangeListener;
    private int snapPosition = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;


    public SnapOnScrollListener(SnapHelper snapHelper, Behavior behavior, OnSnapPositionChangeListener onSnapPositionChangeListener){
        this.snapHelper = snapHelper;
        this.behavior = behavior;
        this.onSnapPositionChangeListener = onSnapPositionChangeListener;
        this.snapHelperExt = new SnapHelperExt();
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        if (behavior == Behavior.NOTIFY_ON_SCROLL) {
            maybeNotifySnapPositionChange(recyclerView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        if (behavior == Behavior.NOTIFY_ON_SCROLL_STATE_IDLE
                && newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            maybeNotifySnapPositionChange(recyclerView);
        }
    }

    private void maybeNotifySnapPositionChange(RecyclerView recyclerView){
        int prevPosition = this.snapHelperExt.getSnapPosition(recyclerView, snapHelper);
        boolean snapPositionIsChanged = (this.snapPosition!=prevPosition);

        if(snapPositionIsChanged){
            onSnapPositionChangeListener.onSnapPositionChange(prevPosition);
            this.snapPosition = prevPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, use it in this way:

```java
            SnapOnScrollListener snapOnScrollListener = new SnapOnScrollListener(
                    snapHelper,
                    SnapOnScrollListener.Behavior.NOTIFY_ON_SCROLL,
                    position -> {   
Log.e(TAG, "currently focused page no = "+position);    
// your code here, do whatever you want
}
            );

            childRecyclerView2.addOnScrollListener(snapOnScrollListener);
```

References:

1. [create-viewpager-using-recyclerview](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/create-viewpager-using-recyclerview-android-ali-ahmed/)
2. [detecting-snap-changes-with-androids-recyclerview](https://medium.com/over-engineering/detecting-snap-changes-with-androids-recyclerview-snaphelper-9e9f5e95c424)