# Horizontal ViewPager2 inside a vertical RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I have a horizontal Viewpager2 inside a vertical Recyclerview. The problem is that the vertical recyclerview is very sensitive and unless the horizontal swipe is exactly in straight line, the view moves in vertical direction. I tried using fakedrag to fix this but couldn't get it right.
A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60313270/how-to-fix-scrolling-issue-of-horizontal-viewpager2-and-recyclerview-that-are-in) but that guy ended up replacing viewpager2 with a recyclerview and using a snapHelper. I son't want to use a recyclerview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using RecyclerView with SnapHelper as mentioned in the answer i referenced in my question.

Sharing the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60313270/how-to-fix-scrolling-issue-of-horizontal-viewpager2-and-recyclerview-that-are-in) again for reference.