# How to implement a "Two Finger Drag" gesture on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gesture

I am new to Android development and am working on an accessibility research project for blind people (Jelly Bean API level 17 project). I have been experimenting with some gestures and the **Two-Finger-Drag** gesture has been really tough to implement. The following image captures what I actually require quite well.

[image: drag gesture]

I want the blind user to drag two fingers across horizontally (anywhere on the screen) and he would obtain an Audio output of the text he/she typed in the EditText. Also according to the distance the two fingers travel while dragging, we output each word separately.(Example below)

> Example: If the user types *"Today is a good day"* and drags his finger
>   (x value) by (say) 10 units to Left we output *"good day"* but if he
>   drags it say 20 units to Left we output *"a good day"*,  for 30 units
>   to Left *"is a good day"* etc etc.

I stumbled across which seems to detect two-finger touch:

```
TouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
```

Also this tutorial on [detecting multiple touches](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/12/detect-multi-touch-for-10-pointers.html) seems promising, but I need it to work for **touch** and **drag** which I am not sure can be implemented like this.

Any new suggestions to implement this or pointers to tutorials that can help would be great!

Thanks in advance,
Adit

Comment: Hello @Adit.. could you share the playstore link please

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Okay So thanks to Gabe here and numerous blogs on this, I have found a solution to my question!

**First I initialized my variables in the "Activity" class**

```
int GLOBAL_TOUCH_POSITION_X = 0;
int GLOBAL_TOUCH_CURRENT_POSITION_X = 0;
```

**Next, Inside the onCreate():**

```
//Two-Finger Drag Gesture detection
    RelativeLayout TextLoggerLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.ActivityrView);
    TextLoggerLayout.setOnTouchListener(
            new RelativeLayout.OnTouchListener(){

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent m) {
                    handleTouch(m); 
                    return true;
                }

    });
```

**Now define the function handleTouch(m) as follows**, it outputs the current position of the "Two-finger-touch" along with the initial position of the touch:

```
void handleTouch(MotionEvent m){
    //Number of touches
    int pointerCount = m.getPointerCount();
    if(pointerCount == 2){
        int action = m.getActionMasked();
        int actionIndex = m.getActionIndex();
        String actionString;
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testDiffText);
        switch (action)
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:                   
                GLOBAL_TOUCH_POSITION_X = (int) m.getX(1);
                actionString = "DOWN"+" current "+GLOBAL_TOUCH_CURRENT_POSITION_X+" prev "+GLOBAL_TOUCH_POSITION_X;
                tv.setText(actionString);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:                 
                GLOBAL_TOUCH_CURRENT_POSITION_X = 0;
                actionString = "UP"+" current "+GLOBAL_TOUCH_CURRENT_POSITION_X+" prev "+GLOBAL_TOUCH_POSITION_X;
                tv.setText(actionString);  
                break;  
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                GLOBAL_TOUCH_CURRENT_POSITION_X = (int) m.getX(1);
                int diff = GLOBAL_TOUCH_POSITION_X-GLOBAL_TOUCH_CURRENT_POSITION_X;
                actionString = "Diff "+diff+" current "+GLOBAL_TOUCH_CURRENT_POSITION_X+" prev "+GLOBAL_TOUCH_POSITION_X;
                tv.setText(actionString);                   
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                GLOBAL_TOUCH_POSITION_X = (int) m.getX(1);
                actionString = "DOWN"+" current "+GLOBAL_TOUCH_CURRENT_POSITION_X+" prev "+GLOBAL_TOUCH_POSITION_X;
                tv.setText(actionString);
                break;
            default:
                actionString = "";
        }

        pointerCount = 0;
    }
    else {
        GLOBAL_TOUCH_POSITION_X = 0;
        GLOBAL_TOUCH_CURRENT_POSITION_X = 0;
    }
}
```

There you have it! The "Two-finger-drag" gesture finally implemented.
Looks, like I can wrte a tiny blog post on it as well!! :)

Comment: could you check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135432/motion-event-single-and-double-finger-swipe) please

Comment: Why you do not use the actionIndex ?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how relevant adding an answer now would be to such an old question but I have been developing [a library](http://github.com/championswimmer/SimpleFingerGestures_Android_Library) to support basic 1 and 2 finger gestures on Android with a very very simple drop in functionality.

Most gestures can be set as easily as

```
view.setOn2FingerGestureListener ( new On2FingerGestureListener () {
@Override 
onSwipeup() {
}
onSwipedown() {
}
});
```

It is open source as well as available to be downloaded as a .jar

Comment: From another [answer by @Arnav](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23048305/431296), the library is here: http://github.com/championswimmer/SimpleFingerGestures_Android_Library

Answer (score 3):

Touch and drag is a series of events.  First you have a down, then you have 1 or more moves, then you have an up.  You detect a starting point on the down, then the drag occurs on the moves.  THe drag stops on an up.

To do a 2 finger drag, only pay attention to drags if `MotionEvent.getPointerCount() == 2`.

Comment: detect the point where the user first touches (the down event).  Store it.  On a move event, check if 2 fingers are down.  If so, check how far its been moved by subtracting the point from the down.  Scroll that much.