# How do you detect a double tap drag?

Tags: java, android, touch, logic, drag

How do you detect a double tap drag?
I am making a game similar to bejeweled, and would like to detect this.
In my current implementation, I was able to get the swipe effects. I would also like to detect the double tap drag effect for a different functionality in the game.

CODE:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent e, int scaledX, int scaledY) {

    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && board.touchBoard(scaledX, scaledY) ) {
        recentTouchY = scaledY;
        recentTouchX = scaledX;

        board.whichCell(scaledX,scaledY);

        touchedCell = board.whichCellTouched(scaledX,scaledY);
        //board.swapClearShape(touchedCell.getOffX(),touchedCell.getOffY());
    } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) { //NEED TO ADD IF TOUCH BOARD AREA

        //swipe event
        if (scaledX - recentTouchX < -25) {

            System.out.println("SWAPPED LEFT");
            Assets.playSound(Assets.swapSound);
            board.setSwapLeft(true);

        }
        else if (scaledX - recentTouchX > 25) {
            System.out.println("SWAPPED RIGHT");
            Assets.playSound(Assets.swapSound);
            board.setSwapRight(true);

        }
        //swap down
        else if(scaledY- recentTouchY > 25){
            System.out.println("SWAPPED DOWN");
            Assets.playSound(Assets.swapSound);
            board.setSwapDown(true);

        }
        //swap up
        else if(scaledY- recentTouchY < -25){
            System.out.println("SWAPPED UP");
            Assets.playSound(Assets.swapSound);
            board.setSwapUp(true);

        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

I am not looking for two finger drag, rather one touch followed by and another touch then drag

Comment: there is a very nice answer on this problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/14873942/1061944

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement a "Two Finger Drag" gesture on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818530/how-to-implement-a-two-finger-drag-gesture-on-android)

Comment: I wasn't looking for two finger drag, rather one touch followed by and another touch then drag.  @Syeda Zunairah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener.html) to detect the double tap gesture and trigger a flag. Then on your onTouch (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) do the drag logic.

If you use the onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) method, you are be able to detect the events between the double tap gesture and trigger the flag before the second ACTION_UP event.

Here's an example of the double tap listener implementation:
http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html