# Limit scrollview to two fingers

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, pan

I have a jot canvas which I want to be scrollable in just vertical direction, but I need to draw on it using single finger.
How can I limit `ScrollView` to respond to "two fingers" and I keep using single finger for painting on my canvas?

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818530/how-to-implement-a-two-finger-drag-gesture-on-android) is really useful for you. Have a quick look. You will have to write this gesture yourself or in the answer there's also  a user who wrote a library for these gestures.